# How to add custom fields to SAML response?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

In the scenario where Salesforce is configured as Identity Provider, how can the SAML assertion returned to authenticating Service Providers be modified to include additional attributes? I cannot see any option for adding custom fields when creating a new connected app and likewise I cannot see any options for doing this when editing an existing connected app - I guess I'm not looking in the right place?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you edit an existing connected app, there should be a section down the bottom called Custom Attributes.

[image]

Here you can set custom fields, and a formula for the values of those fields, to be returned in the SAML response.

From the documentation:

> Each custom attribute must have a unique key and must use fields available from the Insert Field menu. For example, assign a key name, such as `country` and insert the field `$Organization.Country`. **When using SAML, attributes are sent as SAML attribute statements.** When using OAuth, attributes are available as a custom_attributes object in the user’s Identity URL.

For more information, see https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_edit.htm