# Question about using SSO Connected App

Tags: apex, single-sign-on

I was wondering if someone can help me with an issue I have with Single Sign On. I have implemented a Single Sign on with one of our Third Party app using "Connected Apps" in Salesforce. SSO works fine, but I want to pass some additional information such as Account Name, Type, Industry etc. So that a new account is created in Third Party app along with SSO. is there a way I can accomplish this ? I want to pass SAML as well as JSON attribute in the SAML request. This Third Party app allows creating account in SAML request.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80065/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-saml-response

Comment: Thank you dana. I`m already using Custom Attributes to pass additional information that Third party app requires. My questions is more about passing information dynamically. For example, can I create a button on Account which will establish a SSO and well as pass on Account related information ( a JSON format) to Third Party app.  Is there a way to do this using Connected App or writing a manual VF code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a slightly roundabout way by having the trigger event (click on your button) call ApEx/VF code that collects and writes your desired payload to some standard or custom object or merely persists some state (such as Account Id) somewhere. The connected app can then retrieve this payload/state and dynamically create the right attributes. The latter step has to be done in ApEx (can't be in VF) via Connected App plugin: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin.htm

Comment: Thank you identigral. This workaround makes sense. I will give this a try. Thank you again!